# Why does a users $_SESSION variables appear on a different users page?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a simple PHP and MySQL site that validates a user from a database, then sets $_SESSION variables for a membership number, first name and last name.

Today multiple members were logging in at the same time to log activity after an online webinar, and when navigating to different pages other members names were showing up (names are displayed using php echo for the $_SESSION[fname] and [lname]).  I have not seen this happen before, I recently updated my code to use PDO statements etc, but only for database queries, I have not changed the way $_SESSIONs are started or handled, so I don't think that has anything to do with it.

I've tried testing this by logging in from two different browsers with test accounts, but have only gotten it to mess up a few times, then it was working fine again.

How could this happen?  And can someone suggest a way to prevent this from happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My session code is below:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 600)) {
// last request was more than 10 minutes ago
session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the statement:

> > when navigating to different pages other members names were showing up

..this sounds like a different issue. This can happen when a framework/server is using caching, be it local to the server, or service based (varnish, elasticache etc)

Are you using any caching mechanism on the server/in the code or framework you're using? If so, switch it off in the short term, and carry out some more testing. If this does not work, then please update your question with some more information regarding your issue - symptoms, tests to prove, actions taken, etc.

Cheers!

Comment: No caching going on that I'm aware of.  The issue was reported by different people across the country that were logging in and when they would go to a different page it would load with a different members information.  Almost like the $_SESSION wasn't unique to the users own session.  I'm not well informed with sessions.  Would adding anything like `session_id()` or `session_regenerate_id()` help with this?

Comment: Well, you could debug the issue by echoing `session_id()` to show that it is/is not different for each user. If it *is* different, then this might point to an issues with a separate DB query grabbing the user information; if they are the same, then it might appear be a session issue. Be very careful here - if your web application is exposing member data to other members, you'll need to patch very quickly.

Comment: The `session_id()` is the same when I log in with two different logins using two different browsers.  I logged in as one user, then a different user in a different browser.  When I navigate to a different page the second users data showed up in my first login browser.  I definitely need to sort this out, but I have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: If I use my iPad as a third computer, the problem is not replicated.  It seems to respect the separate session.  However on my MacBook, using two different browsers I can always get it to mess up.  Could the IP have something to do with it?  If so, how does it explain people from different parts of the country having this problem at the same time?  I need a more robust solution, I need to start learning more!

Answer (score 0):

I added `session_regenerate_id(TRUE);` after `session_start()` and it seems to have fixed the issue.  My understanding is that this will regenerate the session_id and delete the old.  This still keeps my `$_SESSION` variables active from page to page which is what I need (I don't understand the function well enough to understand why though).

If there is a better solution to this problem, or if I'm creating other issues I'm just not aware of yet, please comment. For now my problem has stopped.

```
<?php session_start();
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
?>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 600)) {
// last request was more than 10 minutes ago
session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp ?>
```